# CSS Sprites - How to Align-bottom all Sprite Buttons

Tags: html, css, css-sprites, sprite

I have 9 Buttons along the bottom nav of my web app (think iOS nav bar - but this is NOT a mobile app).

All buttons are Sprite Images with 3 states.

How do I align all images, i.e. buttons, to the bottom of the nav bar (or div)?  Basically, each icon is slightly different sized, and within the PNG, underneath each icon there is text.

I want all of the text to be aligned, therefore all of the buttons must be bottom-aligned.

How do I do this?  CSS solution?  HTML Solution?

Thanks for your help,

D

See markup below:

```
<html>
<head>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&amp;v2' rel='stylesheet'type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two&amp;v2'  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<style type="text/css">

body {
    background: #000;
     color: #ffffff;
     font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
     font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
    background:#ffffff url('../Background1.png');
    }

 /*Get Boxeeee with it*/
 .box
 {
 width: 1700px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;

 }

 .box a
 {

 float: left;
 margin-right:20px;
 }



 /*Logo CSS Sprites CSS ONLY*/

 .sprite-Bunches-small-normalcopy { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -94px; width: 139px; height: 44px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-Bunches-small-normalcopy:hover { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 0; width: 139px; height: 44px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-Bunches-small-normalcopy:active { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -188px; width: 139px; height: 44px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 


 /*Start Bunches Button CSS ONLY*/

 .sprite-start-regular { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -737px; width: 130px; height: 43px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-start-regular:hover { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -282px; width: 130px; height: 43px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-start-regular:active { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -644px; width: 130px; height: 43px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 /*Press to Talk Button CSS ONLY*/

 .sprite-talk-normal { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -923px; width: 130px; height: 43px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-talk-normal:hover { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -830px; width: 130px; height: 43px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 .sprite-talk-normal:active { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -1016px; width: 130px; height: 43px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }


 /*Camera Pic Button CSS ONLY*/

 .sprite-camera-normal { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -530px; width: 123px; height: 105px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-camera-normal:hover { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -375px; width: 123px; height: 105px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-camera-normal:active { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -685px; width: 123px; height: 105px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 /*Chat Button w/JS (+1 to Hover Y, and -1 to Active(s)), +1 to Active Height*/

 .sprite-chat-normal{ 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -992px; width: 102px; height: 102px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-chat-normal:hover { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -841px; width: 102px; height: 102px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 .sprite-chat-normal:active, .chat-active { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -1143px; width: 102px; height: 103px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 .sprite-chat-normal1:active { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -1144px; width: 102px; height: 102px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }


 /*Invite Button w/JS (+1 to Hover Y, and -1 to Active(s)), +1 to Active Height*/   

 .sprite-invite-normal{ 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -1439px; width: 105px; height: 93px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-invite-normal:hover { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -1297px; width: 105px; height: 93px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 .sprite-invite-normal:active, .invite-active{ 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -1581px; width: 105px; height: 94px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 .sprite-invite-normal1:active { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -1582px; width: 105px; height: 93px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }   



 /*MIC Button w/JS (abs+1 to Hover Y, and abs-1 to Active(s)), +1 to Active Height*/        

 .sprite-mic-normal { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -1886px; width: 74px; height: 111px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-mic-normal:hover { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: 0 -1726px; width: 74px; height: 111px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 .sprite-mic-normal:active, .mic-active { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px 1; width: 74px; height: 112px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

        .sprite-mic-normal1:active{ 
            background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
            background-position: -189px 0; width: 74px; height: 111px; 
            display: block;
            text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
            }   


 /*Music Button w/JS (abs+1 to Hover Y, and abs-1 to Active(s)), +1 to Active Height*/      

 .sprite-music-normal { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -322px; width: 99px; height: 111px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-music-normal:hover { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -162px; width: 99px; height: 111px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 .sprite-music-normal:active, .music-active { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -482px; width: 99px; height: 112px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

    .sprite-music-normal1:active{ 
        background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
        background-position: -189px -483px; width: 99px; height: 111px; 
        display: block;
        text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
        }   


 /*Movie Button w/JS (abs+1 to Hover Y, and abs-1 to Active(s)), +1 to Active Height*/

 .sprite-video-normal { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -1252px; width: 103px; height: 93px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-video-normal:hover { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -1110px; width: 103px; height: 93px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 .sprite-video-normal:active, .video-active{ 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -1394px; width: 103px; height: 94px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

    .sprite-video-normal1:active{ 
        background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
        background-position: -189px -1395px; width: 103px; height: 93px; 
        display: block;
        text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
        } 

 /*Webcam Button w/JS (abs+1 to Hover Y, and abs-1 to Active(s)), +1 to Active Height*/

 .sprite-webcam-normal { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -779px 0; width: 70px; height: 86px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-webcam-normal:hover { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -1929px; width: 70px; height: 86px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 .sprite-webcam-normal:active, .webcam-active { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -779px -136px; width: 81px; height: 89px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

    .sprite-webcam-normal1:active{ 
        background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
        background-position: -779px -136px; width: 81px; height: 89px; 
        display: block;
        text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
        }

 /*Who's Here Button w/JS (abs+1 to Hover Y, and abs-1 to Active(s)), +1 to Active Height*/

 .sprite-who-normal { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -779px -424px; width: 105px; height: 99px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 .sprite-who-normal:hover { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -779px -276px; width: 105px; height: 99px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    } 

 .sprite-who-normal:active, .who-active { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -779px -572px; width: 105px; height: 100px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    .sprite-who-normal1:active { 
        background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
        background-position: -779px -573px; width: 105px; height: 99px; 
        display: block;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        }   



 .sprite-waiting-video { 
    background-image: url('../Images/Sprites/giantsprite.png');
    background-position: -189px -1538px; width: 540px; height: 340px; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
    }   
</style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sprite-chat-normal').click(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('sprite-chat-normal').toggleClass('sprite-chat-normal1').toggleClass('chat-active');
     });   
  });


 /* Invite Button Toggle */

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sprite-invite-normal').click(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('sprite-invite-normal').toggleClass('sprite-invite-normal1').toggleClass('invite-active');
     });   
  });



 /* Mic Button Toggle */

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sprite-mic-normal').click(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('sprite-mic-normal').toggleClass('sprite-mic-normal1').toggleClass('mic-active');
     });   
  });



 /* Music Button Toggle */

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sprite-music-normal').click(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('sprite-music-normal').toggleClass('sprite-music-normal1').toggleClass('music-active');
     });   
  });

 /* Movie Button Toggle */

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sprite-video-normal').click(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('sprite-video-normal').toggleClass('sprite-video-normal1').toggleClass('video-active');
     });   
  });



 /* Webcam Button Toggle */

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sprite-webcam-normal').click(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('sprite-webcam-normal').toggleClass('sprite-webcam-normal1').toggleClass('webcam-active');
     });   
  });


 /* Who's Here Button Toggle */

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sprite-who-normal').click(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('sprite-who-normal').toggleClass('sprite-who-normal1').toggleClass('who-active');
     });   
  });


 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="box">
 <!--<a class="sprite-Bunches-small-normalcopy" href="#"></a>
 <a class="sprite-start-regular" href="#"></a>  
 <a class="sprite-talk-normal" href="#"></a>-->
 <a class="sprite-camera-normal" href="#"></a> 
 <a class="sprite-chat-normal" href="#"></a>
 <a class="sprite-invite-normal" href="#"></a>
 <div style="float:right;">
 <a class="sprite-mic-normal" href="#"></a>
 <a class="sprite-music-normal" href="#"></a>
 <a class="sprite-video-normal" href="#"></a>
 <a class="sprite-webcam-normal" href="#"></a>
 <a class="sprite-who-normal" href="#"></a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why don't you show the HTML here? You might be able to use absolute-positioning or use left: x and top:y for this.

Comment: Thx, just added the markup and the HTML is at the bottom :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like more of a photoshop-chopping question than anything. Here's how I would approach, assuming that your markup is structured as follows:

```
<nav>
     <ul>
          <li class="icon-a">
               <a>
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    Text
               </a>
          </li>

          <li class="icon-b">
               <a>
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    Text
               </a>
          </li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

Find height of the tallest icon and set that as the height of your `<li>`. Then find the width of the widest icon and set that as the width of your `<li>`.

You'll have to layout the icons in your sprite file very carefully, and space the icons evenly according to max width and height that I mentioned above (I would use photoshop rulers and guides to create a grid make your life easier). Each icon state should be in a row. The key to aligning the icons on the bottom is how you lay out the icons in photoshop.

I would do it this way assuming your tallest icon is 40px and your widest icon is 30px. I am setting the height to 60px so there is room at the bottom for the text to go underneath the icon.

```
nav li {
   width: 30px;
   height: 60px;
   display: block;
   float: left;
}

nav li a {
   width: 30px;
   height: 60px;
   line-height: 15px;
   display: block;
   text-align: center
}

nav li a span {
   width: 30px;
   height: 40px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   display: block;
   background: url(icons.png) no-repeat
}

nav li.icon-a span {background-position: 0 0}
nav li.icon-a span:hover {background-position: 0 -40px}
nav li.icon-a span:active {background-position: 0 -80px}

nav li.icon-b span {background-position: -30px 0}
nav li.icon-b span:hover {background-position: -30px -40px}
nav li.icon-b span:active {background-position: -30px -80px}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what size each icon is, you should make your sprite with evenly positioned icons on it.

If you have a space of lets say 36 x 36px for each button, then you need to place each icon already aligned at the bottom of a 36x36 square in your sprite, then you just position the sprite using a 36px grid.

Comment: I did have all my individual PNGs the way you recommend.  Since there are many PNGs i put them all on one giant PNG via CSS Sprite Generator (http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) which gives me all the coordinates of each image.

Comment: I see now that you have the buttons (apart from the icons) in a variety of sizes from 43px to 112px height. That will require a lot of manual I think, including editing the sprite.